# Try-Catch Exception handling

Tags: java

```
try {
    System.out.println("how many times");
    rollnumber = scanner.nextInt();
    nigh=2;
 }catch (Exception e){
    System.out.print("invalid. re-enter");
 }     
 }while (nigh==1);
```

It keeps printing out infinity "invalid re-enterhow many times"

Comment: Your code not even compile post your actual code and clarify your issue

Comment: Please add scanner.nextInt() within a scanner.hasNextInt() if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get into an infinite loop because `scanner.nextInt();` does not consume characters from the input on error. Change the `catch` clause as follows to make it work:

```
try {
    ... // Your code
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.print("invalid. re-enter");
    scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: How you jump into that conclusion by looking at OP's buggy code?

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera There is enough in his code to see that this is what's happening (I also ran into a problem like this before).

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera OP told `infinity` which means he entered something which Scanner was not expecting so scanner.nextLine(); in catch probably fix it by telling scanner to allow him to re-enter

Comment: @M.Sharma yes I can see that. I never put an answer for this kind of question.